# how to calculate time complexity in DFS?

Tags: c++, time-complexity, depth-first-search

I would like to know precisely how the time complexity of the DFS algorithm is calculated when using an adjacency list as the storage structure. Additionally, I want to understand the general approach to calculating time complexity. Is it about counting how many times a particular crucial step is executed? Which step should be considered the crucial step in this case? Could you provide the specific steps to calculate the time complexity of the DFS algorithm?

I tried to find a certain statement to count for time complexity.and i can't find the right and specific way to calculate it.

```
//here is the data struct
typedef struct ArcNode
{
    int adjvex;
    ArcNode* nextarc;
    ArcType info;
}ArcNode;

typedef struct VNode
{
    VexType data;
    ArcNode* firstarc;
}VNode, AdjList[MVNum];

typedef struct Graph
{
    AdjList vertices;
    int vexnum, arcnum;
}ALGraph;
bool visited[MVNum];
enum Status
{
    OK,
    ERROR
};
Status(*visitFunc)(int);
Status printout(int v)
{
    cout << G.vertices[v].data << endl;
    return OK;
}

//above are some variable definitions, and below are the key DFS algorithms.

void DFS(ALGraph G, int v)
{
    visitFunc(v);
    visited[v] = true;
    ArcNode* w = G.vertices[v].firstarc;
    //this for loop is for traverse the adjacent points.
    for (; w != NULL; w = w->nextarc)
    {
        if (!visited[v])//Should I look at how many times I compare here to calculate the time complexity?
            DFS(G, w->adjvex);//or look at this statement?
    }
}
void DFSTraverse(ALGraph G, Status(*visit)(int v))
{
    int v;
    visitFunc = visit;
    for (v = 0; v < G.vexnum; v++)
    {
        visited[v] = false;
    }
    for (v = 0; v < G.vexnum; v++)
    {
        if (!visited[v])
            DFS(G, v);
    }
}
```

Why is the time complexity is `O(N+E)`? `N` is the number of vex and `E` is the number of arc.my question is should I look at how many times I compare "if (!visited[v])" to calculate the time complexity.

Comment: Please sumbit your code to codereview.stackexchange.com, because there are several things that are very non-idiomatic for C++ that will hinder you in the long term.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score -2):

### An Example of Traversing Using DFS

Suppose we have the following directed graph.

[image: A 4-Node Graph Cyclic Graph]

4-Node Graph with cycles that we’ll use in our examples.

1. The DFS algorithm starts at the root vertex **A**. It visits it and adds it to the visited set.
2. The algorithm follows the edge from **A->B** to visit vertex **B** and adds it to the visited set.
3. B has two neighbors: C and D. It arbitrarily picks up the edge from **B->C** and visits vertex **C**. It adds vertex **C** to the visited set.
4. It *follows* the edge from **C->A**. Upon arriving it **A**, it realizes it has visited it already so it backtracks to **C** to visit its next neighbor.
5. It then follows the edge from **C->D** and adds **D** to the visited set since it hasn’t visited it before.
6. It then backtracks to **C** and then to **B**. It follows the remaining edge from **B->D**. However, upon arriving at **D**, it realizes that it has visited it already.
7. The backtracking continues and the algorithm ends since it has visited all the vertices.

#### Time Complexity of DFS

The time complexity of DFS algorithm depends on the specific implementation and the characteristics of the graph or tree which it is traversing.

Let **V** be the number of vertices (or nodes) in the graph and **E** be the number of edges.

##### Different Graph Representations

In the case of a graph represented as an **adjacency matrix**, the time complexity may be O(V^2) due to the need to check all possible edges for each vertex. On the other hand, if the graph is represented as an **adjacency list**, the time complexity is often O(V + E).

Remember, **visiting a node** is the *"particular crucial step is executed"*.

##### Best Case

In the best case, DFS has a time complexity of *O(V)*. If the graph is a tree (i.e. has no cycles and each node has exactly one parent node, except for the root) then the algorithm only needs to visit the vertices of the graph, and not the edges. In this case, the time taken is directly proportional to the number of vertices in the graph.

```
        A
       / \
      B   C
     /   / \
    D   E   F
```

##### Worst Case

In the worst case, DFS has a time complexity of *O(V + E)*. This is because the DFS algorithm will need to visit some nodes and edges more than once so it could explore the entire graph.

The DFS algorithm we explored above visited every node and every edge. In total, it visited **4** vertices and **5** edges. Therefore, the time complexity of the algorithm is:

```
O(V + E) = O(4 + 5) = O(9)
```

Where V is the number of vertices (or nodes) in the graph and E is the number of edges

In general, the time complexity of DFS is **O(V + E)**, but it can be as good as *O(V)* if the graph is a tree.

The worst-case **space** complexity if O(V) since it needs to store the set of visited vertices or a stack of vertices.

Comment: Wow a complete copy of an online article